# custom Listview with Checkbox, dual selection

Tags: android, listview, custom-controls

I have a custom listview and i would like to select the checkbox in two way, the first if the user click on the checkbox and the other if the user click on the item of listview.

this is the code:

```
       public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            final int position = pos;
            User p = getProduct(position);
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                vgparent = parent;
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row2, vgparent, false);//null);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_prodotto);
                holder.qty_ing = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qta1);
                holder.qty_risc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qta2);
                holder.cbView = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            if(holder.name != null) {
                holder.name.setText(data.get(position).getName());
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// this is the problem
//
//
                holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ViewHolder holder = null;
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        View convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row2, vgparent, false);
                        holder.cbView = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
                        holder.cbView.setChecked(true);
                    }
                });
            }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if(holder.qty_ing != null) {
                // verifica la coincidenza per poter cambiare colore
                if(data.get(position).getName().equals(nameing))
                    holder.qty_ing.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                else
            holder.qty_ing.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

                holder.qty_ing.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getQtyIng()));
            }
            if(holder.qty_risc != null) {
                holder.qty_risc.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getQtyRis()));
            }
            if(holder.cbView != null) {
                holder.cbView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    //@Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
                    if(isChecked){
                        qty_risc += GetDoubleVal(data.get(position).getQtyRis());
                        qty_ing += GetDoubleVal(data.get(position).getQtyIng());
                    }else {
                        qty_risc -= GetDoubleVal(data.get(position).getQtyRis());
                        qty_ing -= GetDoubleVal(data.get(position).getQtyIng());
                    }
                    listener.onTotalChanged(qty_risc, qty_ing);
                    }
                });
                holder.cbView.setTag(position);
                holder.cbView.setChecked(p.box);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

I have implemented the checkbox click and works fine, but the other way (click on item of listview) is very difficult for me.

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would just click the layout rather than the both.  It would do the same exact thing.

Comment: the problem is how can check the checkbox inside the getView...